# Facing the list of errors while installing jenkins on UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, installation, devops, ubuntu-16.04

The errors are

1. release file not available
2. data from the repository cant be authenticated
3. server certification failed
4. some idex files failed to download

[image: screenshot showing errors]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Also, the screenshot doesn't show the full output. Make sure you copy-paste the whole thing.

Comment: And it's worth noting that Ubuntu 16 is out of (free) support. If you can, use Ubuntu 18 or ideally 20.